# How to use MergeHub w/ Flow.mapAsync()

Tags: java, akka-stream

I'm kind of confused how to use `MergeHub`.

I'm designing a flow graph that uses `Flow.mapAsync()`, where the given function creates another flow graph, and then runs it with `Sink.ignore()`, and returns that `CompletionStage` as the value for `Flow.mapAsync()` to wait for. The nested flow will return elements via the `Sink` returned from materializing the `MergeHub`.

The issue is that I need to provide the `Function` which starts the nested flow to `Flow.mapAsync()` when I'm creating the top-level flow graph, but that requires it to have access to the materialized value returned from materializing the result of `MergeHub.of()`. How do I get that materialized value before starting the flow graph?

The only way I can see right now is to implement the `Function` to block until the `Sink` has been provided (after starting the top-level flow graph), but that seems pretty hacky.

So, something like

```
class MapAsyncFunctor implements Function<T, CompletionStage<Done>> {...}
MapAsyncFunctor mapAsyncFunctor = new MapAsyncFunctor();
RunnableGraph<Sink<T>> graph = createGraph(mapAsyncFunctor);
Sink<T> sink = materializer.materialize(graph);
mapAsyncFunctor.setSink(sink); // Graph execution blocked in background in call to mapAsyncFunctor.apply() until this is done
```

---

Edit: I've created the following class

```
public final class Channel<T>
{
    private final Sink<T, NotUsed> m_channelIn;
    private final Source<T, NotUsed> m_channelOut;
    private final UniqueKillSwitch m_killSwitch;

    public Channel(Class<T> in_class, Materializer in_materializer)
    {
        final Source<T, Sink<T, NotUsed>> source = MergeHub.of(in_class);
        final Sink<T, Source<T, NotUsed>> sink = BroadcastHub.of(in_class);

        final Pair<Pair<Sink<T, NotUsed>, UniqueKillSwitch>, Source<T, NotUsed>> matVals = in_materializer.materialize(source.viaMat(KillSwitches.single(), Keep.both()).toMat(sink, Keep.both()));

        m_channelIn = matVals.first().first();
        m_channelOut = matVals.second();
        m_killSwitch = matVals.first().second();
    }

    public Sink<T, NotUsed> in()
    {
        return m_channelIn;
    }

    public Source<T, NotUsed> out()
    {
        return m_channelOut;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        m_killSwitch.shutdown();
    }
}
```

so that I can get a Source/Sink pair to use in building the graph. Is this a good idea? Will I 'leak' these channels if I don't explicitly close()
them?

I'll only ever need to use .out() once for my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

With `MergeHub` you **always** need to materialize the hub sink before doing anything else.

```
Sink<T, NotUsed> toConsumer = MergeHub.of(String.class, 16).to(consumer).run(materializer);
```

You can then distribute it to all bits of code that need to materialize it to send data to it. Following your snippet above, a possible approach might be passing the `Sink` your functor at construction time:

```
class MapAsyncFunctor implements Function<T, CompletionStage<Done>> {

    private Sink<T, NotUsed> sink;

    public MapAsyncFunctor(Sink<T, NotUsed> sink) {
        this.sink = sink;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Done> apply(T t) { /* run substream into sink */ }
}

MapAsyncFunctor mapAsyncFunctor = new MapAsyncFunctor(toConsumer);

// run your flow with mapAsync on the above functor
```

More info on `MergeHub` can be found in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-mergehub).

Comment: I wanted to use MergeHub in the creation of a cycle in my flow graph, which doesn't really work here. Maybe I can use both a MergeHub and a BroadcastHub together, and create a Source/Sink pair which I can use in creating my graph...